# Cookiecutter Django Docker Hot Reloading Not Detecting Changes

Tags: django, docker, cookiecutter-django

I have recently created a new Docker project using cookiecutter-django. I've done this before and "hot reloading" has worked, however for some reason changes are not being detected properly in this project. The docs start to reload, and then detect no changes, as shown in the image below. Does anyone know why this is, or how to fix it?

Thanks for any help anyone can offer!

[image]

Comment: A Docker container is an isolated environment, and normally the code in a container isn't connected to anything you might be editing in an IDE.  Can you use plain Python without Docker for development?  Have you done anything to cause live reloading to work?  How is the PNG file in the question related to the development process?